# Obter raio de aproximação a partir de uma coordenada geográfica

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, gps

Tenho uma aplicação PHP que obtém a latitude e longitude de um endereço, utilizando a API do Google Maps. A ideia é delimitar uma distância de "tolerância" em torno deste ponto para, posteriormente, validar se o usuário está dentro do raio delimitado.

**A partir deste único ponto que tenho, como posso fazer para obter as coordenadas de um raio de *x* metros em torno deste ponto?**

Caso não haja como fazer desta maneira, como posso definir uma distância de tolerância que o usuário pode estar do ponto definido?

**OBS.:** Não preciso exibir um raio no front-end do mapa (como mostrado aqui: [Como faço para ciar um mapa com uma circunferência de proximação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213270/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-ciar-um-mapa-com-uma-circunfer%c3%aancia-de-proxima%c3%a7%c3%a3o)), mas sim uma maneira de, por exemplo, calcular se uma coordenada A está dentro de um raio de x metros da coordenada B.

Comment: Veja se isto resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213270/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-ciar-um-mapa-com-uma-circunfer%C3%AAncia-de-proxima%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para ciar um mapa com uma circunferência de proximação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213270/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-ciar-um-mapa-com-uma-circunfer%c3%aancia-de-proxima%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: @bfavaretto Este exemplo mostra como fazer a circunferência graficamente, no front-end. Mas continua tendo apenas uma coordenada. Eu preciso de uma maneira de verificar se as coordenadas da localização do usuário estão dentro deste raio de aproximação.

Comment: @AndréRaubach Basta calcular a distância do ponto do usuário até o centro da circunferência. Se a distância for menor que o raio ele estará dentro dela.

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson! Depois que vc falou, ficou até óbvio. Kkkkk
E pra calcular, dá pra usar a fórmula de Haversine pra calcular a distância em linha reta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai resolver isso utilizando essa [biblioteca](https://packagist.org/packages/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial) para o **Laravel**, ela trabalha com tipos de dados espaciais no **MySQL**. Essa biblioteca tem diversos métodos para trabalhar com coordenadas, polygons, distância e etc.

Após seguir a documentação para instalação e configuração da mesma, você vai ter mais ou menos isso:

**Migration** da sua tabela de endereço ou tabela que vai possuir o lat e lng:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('zipcode');
    $table->integer('neighborhood');
    $table->string('street');
    $table->string('number');
    $table->string('complement');
    $table->string('landmark');
    $table->point('location'); // Lat e Long
    $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1)->comment('0=Disabled, 1=Enabled');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Model**:

```
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;

class Mall extends Model
{
    use SpatialTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['zipcode', 'neighborhood', 'street', 'number', 'complement', 'landmark', 'location', status];
}
```

**Controller**:

```
use App\Address; // Namespace do seu model
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;

class BikerQueueController extends Controller
{

    public function calcRadius( Request $request )
    {
        $lat = $request->input( 'lat' );
        $lng = $request->input( 'lng' );

        // O método distanceSphere() é da lib instalada, 
        // você deve informar 3 parâmetros: distanceSphere($geometryColumn, $geometry, $distance); A distância deve ser informada em milhas.
        $address = Address::distanceSphere( 'location', new Point( $lat, $lng ), 5000 )
                    ->whereStatus( 1 ) // Aqui é um exemplo de que você pode usar os métodos padrões do seu model junto com os métodos da lib
                    ->first();

        return (bool)$address; // retorna true ou false
    }
}
```

> P.S: Por favor abstrai o tratamento das variáveis do request e do retorno do método, o foco era só mostrar como você pode fazer para saber se uma coordenada está dentro do raio de um endereço.

Comment: Opa! Estou usando Laravel no projeto mesmo. Não conhecia essa biblioteca. Mas pelo que li, parece que resolve meu problema. Vou implementar logo mais. Por hora, já vou marcar como resposta. Muito obrigado pela dica, Kayo!

Comment: Ao testar seu exemplo, estou recebendo a exceção "Call to undefined method App\Adress::distanceSphere".

Comment: Amigo no seu model você importou a lib?
`use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;`
E deu o use dentro do model?
`class Model {
    use SpatialTrait;
}`

Comment: Sim. Importei a lib e coloquei o _use SpatialTrait_ no Model, utilizei tanto a implementação do seu exemplo quanto a da documentação. Também adicionei o Provider no config\app.php. Por isso, não compreendi a razão de o sistema não reconhecer a função.

Comment: Resolvido. Atualizei o pacote com o composer update e passou a funcionar. Por algum motivo, deve ter instalado uma versão desatualizada.